# Taking first 2 values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In the first column of a file I am looking at, it reads a list of 7 different comma separated values, like so:
alex,43,37,12,1,2,5

There are 2000 more rows that are set up the same way.

I only am interested in the first 2, the rest are unimportant to me. I am trying to assign the first two values into separate columns in my dataframe, like so:

```
 typesx = (line.split(",") for line in df['firstcolumn'])
ty=((type[0], type[1]) for type in typesx)
for z in range(len(df)):
    df['firstplaceholder'][z] = type(0)
    df['secondplaceholder'][z] = type(1)
```

However, this only places the type into the respective columns (i.e int, string), go figure.

I am confused because if I choose to print type 0 and type 1, it will print what I am looking for (in this case alex, 43). 
Like so:

```
for a,b in ty:

    print(a,b)
```

However, I am unsure how to copy these values into the separate columns I have created (firstplaceholder, secondplaceholder).

Comment: How are you reading this CSV? Is it intended that you have multiple values in the first column in the first place?

Comment: @U8-Forward I'd say it's almost guaranteed, which is why I edited the tag in

Comment: First of all, it's not good to have an something called a python keyword, that will over-right the existing keyword

Comment: @roganjosh unfortunately yeah, this isn't a CSV. but yes, thats how the file it is set up.

Comment: @U8-Forward thank you, I have changed it to a non - python keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are making the mistake while retrieving the values. Try the below code.

`df['firstplaceholder'][z] = ty[z][0]
 df['secondplaceholder'][z] = ty[z][1]`

Comment: I also suggest changing all occurrences of `type` to some other name (say, `val`). `type` is a native Python function and it is a bad idea to use it in some other way.

Comment: this worked! can't believe I didn't try this.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={"1":["a,bb,c,d"],"2":["n,g,r,h,l"]},index=['firstcolumn']).T

df['secondcolumn']=df['firstcolumn'].apply(lambda s:s.split(',')[1])
df['firstcolumn'] =df['firstcolumn'].apply(lambda s:s.split(',')[0])
```